# unable to understand pandas index selection working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am just exploring some code and then I saw this I am trying to understand this code `df.columns[df.isna().any()]` I know that is returning a column that has null value but what funcntionality work here `df.isna().any` give me series with column name and bool like this

```
Survived       False
Pclass         False
Name           False
Sex            False
Age             True
SibSp          False
Parch          False
Ticket         False
Fare           False
Cabin           True
Embarked        True
dtype: bool
```

but I am just confused how this functionality work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

1. `df.isna()` checks if each cell is none or nan
2. `df.isna().any()` further checks if there is any True in column
3. `df.columns[df.isna().any()]` is boolean indexing which keeps True

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if DataFrame has a NaN value, you can use the isnull().values.any() method that returns True if DataFrame has a NaN value. False if there is no NaN entry in the DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df=pd.DataFrame({
                'Student':['Hisila', 'Shristi','Zeppy','Alina','Jerry'],
                'Height':[1.63,1.5,np.nan,np.nan,1.4],
                'Weight':[np.nan,56,73,np.nan,44]
                })

check_for_nan = df.isnull().values.any()
print (check_for_nan)
```

Print

```
True
```

df.isnull().values returns the NumPy representation of the data frame. numpy.any() returns True if any of the elements are evaluated as True.

Therefore, if there is a NaN in the data frame, df.isnull().values.any() is True.

Check if there's a NaN
df.isnull().any().any()
df.any() returns which element is true. If df is a data frame, pd.Series, df pd.Series returns a Boolean value.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df=pd.DataFrame({
                'Student':['Hisila', 'Shristi','Zeppy','Alina','Jerry'],
                'Height':[1.63,1.5,np.nan,np.nan,1.4],
                'Weight':[np.nan,56,73,np.nan,44]
                })

check_for_nan = df.isnull().any().any()

print(check_for_nan)
```

Print

```
True
```

pandas.DataFrame.isna() method

The method for pandas.DataFrame.isna() is as follows: panas.DataFrame.isnull(). There is no difference in the operation of the two methods. Only the name is different.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df=pd.DataFrame({
                'Student':['Hisila', 'Shristi','Zeppy','Alina','Jerry'],
                'Height':[1.63,1.5,np.nan,np.nan,1.4],
                'Weight':[np.nan,56,73,np.nan,44]
                })

df_check=df.isna()

check_for_any_nan= df.isna().values.any()
# Or
check_for_any_nan= df.isna().any().any()
total_nan_values = df.isna().sum().sum()
print(df_check)
print("NaN Presence:"+str(check_for_any_nan))
print ("Total Number of NaN values:"+str(total_nan_values))
```

Print

```
   Student  Height  Weight
0    False   False    True
1    False   False   False
2    False    True   False
3    False    True    True
4    False   False   False
NaN Presence:True
Total Number of NaN values:4
```

If you want to know the number of missing values, do the following

```
df.isna().sum()
```

Print

```
Student    0
Height     2
Weight     2
dtype: int64
```

Also you use df.info() can check null

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------   --------------  -----  
 0   Student  5 non-null      object 
 1   Height   3 non-null      float64
 2   Weight   3 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 248.0+ bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [this (.isna)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) could help you, also you can checkout [this (.any)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)

In short, it returns a boolean same-sized object indicating if the values are NA.